# Visual Studio 2015 RC Displaying Non-English Characters

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have a problem with Visual Studio 2015 RC displaying non-English characters (trying to avoid saying Chinese characters since I'm not 100% sure what character set this is).
Here are some images:

[image: New Project Dialog]

[image: Some Dialog after double-clicking a solution from Source Control Explorer (TFS)]

This only started since Monday, May 18. I just need ideas of where to check to fix this issue, or maybe I just do a repair on the installation.

UPDATE:
I did want to update this post with one additional screenshot because it might be important. This screenshot shows the TeamFoundationEnvironment node under Options -> Source Control with the Chinese characters.
[image: TeamFoundationEnvironment node]

What's interesting is that it's the only node that has the characters. Could it be TFS-related?

Thanks,

Comment: yes, those are chinese characters, Chinese Traditional to be exact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there were already posts about this issue (except I didn't know what to search for until I got a little deeper into it [basically when I found the TeamFoundationEnvironment node in Chinese]).

The fix per connect.microsoft.com is to do a **repair**, and the issue is a known one attributed from doing a CTP6->RTM upgrade of VS 2015.
Here's the link to Microsoft Connect: [link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1307822/teamfoundationenvironment-in-chinese)

Another post related to this, but does not have the details of the fix is this one:
[ASP.NET Forums](http://forums.asp.net/t/2048080.aspx?Chinese%20characters%20display%20in%20VS%202015%20RC)

So maybe there's an underlying message from all of this. Don't do a CTP6->RTM upgrade. Uninstall CTP6, first.

Comment: The repair did in fact fix the problem. Additionally, instead of the node being called "TeamFoundationEnvironment", the node is now called "Environment".

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly likely a system locale issue. (or a possibly bug)

To [change the system locale language](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-system-locale#1TC=windows-7):

> Open **Region and Language** by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, clicking **Control Panel**, clicking **Clock, Language, and Region**, and then clicking **Region and Language**.
>
> Click the **Administrative** tab, and then, under **Language for non-Unicode**
>   programs, click **Change system locale**.  Administrator permission
>   required If you're prompted for an administrator password or
>   confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
>
> Select the language, and then click OK. (You want **English**, I assume)
>
> To restart your computer, click **Restart now**.

**Alternatively**, this will only change the language setting of VS2015: (this was tested on VS2012, I do not have 2015)

Tools (next to SQL) -> Options (last one, gear icon) -> Environment (first item on the left) -> "International settings" (7th item counting from bottom) then "Language" setting (on right pane). On my system, the two choices are "English" and "Same as Microsoft Windows". Try English.

Comment: Thanks. I should've mentioned that I did check there already (sorry). But I did go through those steps just to verify and the "Current system locale" is already set to "English (United States)"

Comment: International Settings also show "English" as the selected "Language"

Comment: On another note, I found a connect.microsoft.com post about it (and also in the ASP.NET forums). Seems the solution is to do a repair. I will post the answer referring to the posts. Thank you so much for replying.

Comment: @jgo maybe it's a bug. if an older version of VS on that system doesn't display chinese (you didn't mention if you tried checking an older version) then you've narrowed it down to it being an RC issue. I'm out of ideas :/

Comment: @jgo good to know you found a solution (did it work?) glad to have been of some help.

Comment: The repair, which is the current solution, will take some time to run. I will definitely update this thread later whether it worked or not. thanks again!